# Pekin Chang'e 4 Mission, Shadow?

Tags: the-moon, moonlanding

I'm wondering why there is a shadow under the Yutu 2 rover, of the Chang'e 4 mission, since it is on the far/dark side of the moon.

[image]
<sup>The Chang'e 4 lander, as seen by the Yutu 2 rover. (Image credit: CNSA)</sup>

[See the Far Side of the Moon in This Amazing Panorama from China's Chang'e 4 Lander](https://www.space.com/42981-china-moon-far-side-panorama-chang-e-4.html)

Comment: @JanDoggen it's a great edit, maybe the title can be adjusted as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh sorry, I just understand what is going on. Being the far side of the moon, did not mean that it's never exposed to the sun.
So the Expression "Dark Side Of The Moon" is not so true.

Has  written in Wikidepia :

*Tidal forces from Earth have slowed down the Moon's rotation to the point where the same side is always facing the Earth—a phenomenon called tidal locking. The other face, most of which is never visible from the Earth, is therefore called the "far side of the Moon". Over time, some parts of the far side can be seen due to libration.[7] In total, 59 percent of the Moon's surface is visible from Earth at one time or another. Useful observation of the parts of the far side of the Moon occasionally visible from Earth is difficult because of the low viewing angle from Earth (they cannot be observed "full on").*

*The phrase "dark side of the Moon" does not refer to "dark" as in the absence of light, but rather "dark" as in unknown: until humans were able to send spacecraft around the Moon, this area had never been seen.[1][2][3][4] While many misconstrue this to think that the "dark side" receives little to no sunlight, in reality, both the near and far sides receive (on average) almost equal amounts of light directly from the Sun. However, the near side also receives sunlight reflected from the Earth, known as earthshine. Earthshine does not reach the area of the far side that cannot be seen from Earth. Only during a full Moon (as viewed from Earth) is the whole far side of the Moon dark. The word "dark" has expanded to refer also to the fact that communication with spacecraft can be blocked while the spacecraft is on the far side of the Moon, during Apollo space missions for example.*